# Cmake error: Cannot specify link libraries for target

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to build a simple CMake project but I'm having problems understanding CMake or at least the error I get.

The project i made is divided in a couple directories.
The main one has this cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7.2)
project(Raytracer)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_subdirectory(src)
set(COMMON_INCLUDES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc)
```

From there my project splits in 2 folders src and inc.
and in src i have the following cmake with the idea to global all subfolders:

```
FILE(GLOB sub-dirs RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} *)
FOREACH(dir ${sub-dirs})
    IF(IS_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${dir})
        ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(${dir})
    ENDIF()
ENDFOREACH()

add_executable(raytracer main.cpp)
```

I also add the executable there which is in this main src folder.
From there on i want to be able to make sub folders adding with their own Cmake files and linking those files to my executable.
I have the following cmake:

```
set(OBJECTS
    asdf.cpp
    )

add_library(obj_files ${OBJECTS} ${COMMON_FILES})
target_link_libraries(raytracer obj_files)
```

but when I try to build I get the following error:

```
Cannot specify link libraries for target "raytracer" which is not built by this project.
```

Comment: You should **create a target** (`raytracer` in your case) **before use it** in `target_link_libraries` and other commands which expects targets.

Answer (score 2):

Basically in `Cmake` file or `toolchain.cmake` the order of commands are important!
`target_link_libraries()` or `target_include_directories()` have to be always `after add_executable()`